# What happens when all heroes and elite heroes are dealt in Boss Monster?

Tags: boss-monster

A group of 4 managed to get through all the heroes and elite heroes in Boss Monster without any clear winner (10 souls)

How do we determine who won?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer from one of the game's creators in [this thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/997751/running-out-heroes-ordinary-hero-epic-hero-deck) on BGG.  It states

> If a turn ends and all Hero cards have been claimed or removed from
>   the game, the tiebreaker rules apply.